# The second monitor displays with a resolution of 640x480

Tags: xorg, multi-monitor, resolution

The system does not detect my second monitor connected the DVI. Appears in the settings of the words "digital device" and adjustment increase that I can set the resolution to 640x480. At D_SUB see each correctly.

What do I need to do to properly operate the space of two monitors?

system - Linux Mint 13,
Graphics Card - GeFroce GT520,
monitor 1 - ViewSonic VA1903wb (plugged into D_SUB),
monitor 2 - LG Flatron L1919S ( plugged into DVI using an adapter DVI--> D_SUB,
the nvidia drivers - version 304.60

Result of `xrandr -q` command.

```
xrandr -q

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2080 x 900, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected 640x480+1440+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        59.9*+
   320x240       120.1  
VGA-0 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 256mm
   1440x900       59.9*+   75.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

My xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 304.60  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-13)  Sun Oct 14 21:19:07 PDT 2012

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 304.60  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-13)  Sun Oct 14 21:19:18 PDT 2012

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-0"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 520"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT-0: nvidia-auto-select +1440+0, CRT-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I tried to add the code below, but it did not help.

```
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "LG Flatron L1919S"
HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
Modeline       "1280x960_60.00"  102.10  1280 1360 1496 1712  960 961 964 994  -HSync +Vsync
Option         "DPMS"
```

This may be due to the adapter?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, the problem was on the side of the adapter. After replacing the adapter to another, the monitor is properly detected now it can also be freely configured.